# Socket Exceptions due to density in Nodejs with WebSocket

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, websocket, socket.io

I have node js server that is connected the 10k-14k client with WebSocket.

When client count is up to above about ~14k, new clients begin to get the exception that:

> "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it"

As far as I know, this exception does not occur about network density. Because connection(port count) limit 65k. If there is an available port, I think another exception should occur about density. For example, if the server can not handle the 15k connection, I think this exception should not occur.

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It actually may depend on various reasons, for example, your server has limited ram and therefore can not create any more connections, or your process cannot handle this amount. You can try to scale your server with node.js Cluster, for example, there are libraries to scale WebSocket:

https://github.com/ClusterWS/ClusterWS

But if there are problems with RAM usage this library won't help.